# JAVA : Create a txt file with name end with timestamp But Its type still remains .TEXT file only

Tags: java, file, text

I created a text file with name `ABCD.text.<currentTimeStamp>`
But When I see it in List mode, Its Type is `ABCD.text.<currentTimeStamp>` only.
I want its type remain as Text file only.
Please suggest

Comment: You should tell us what you mean by "I see it in List mode" (what list mode??)

Comment: This is not particularly clear. Can you please give a better example?

Comment: It's not really a Java issue. Most operating systems determine the file type from its suffix (in Unix/Linux this is usually only significant in graphical desktop environments). So you need to name your files with an appropriate suffix.

Comment: `ABCD.text.<currentTimeStamp>.txt` is probably suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Create it with `"ABCD.text.txt"` (or `"ABCD.txt"` if in your listing mode you want to see just ABCD as file name).